# How to get in-between attribute value of a d3 element while a transition is going on?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to build a simple svg game to catch a moving circle. There is a `catchCircle`, a moving `preyCircle` and a *Catch Me* button. `catchCircle` starts moving vertically from bottom of the screen, crosses `preyCircle` and gets disappeared at the top. The idea is to click the button when the `preyCircle` overlaps the `catchCircle`. In that case I just need to check if the distance of `cy` attributes of both the circle is less than sum of their `radius`.

Problem I am facing here is to get the `cy` attribute of `catchCircle` while the transition is going on. If I try to get `preyCircle.attr('cy')` from inside `onclick` event method, error is shown:
"Uncaught Error: too late; already running"

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
<button id="catchMe"> Catch Me </button>
<span id="msg"></span>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
const width = 200, height = 300, radius = 10;
const svg = d3.select('#canvas')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

const catchCircle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('cx', width / 2)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)
  .attr('fill', 'none');

const preyCircle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('cx', width / 2)
  .attr('cy', height - radius)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .delay(1000)
    .attr('cy', radius)
    .remove();

d3.select('#catchMe')
  .on('click', () => {
    catched = false;

    // Need to get if catchCircle and preyCircle overlapped while clicking
    // I am stuck here!!!

    const msgSpan = d3.select('#msg');
    msgSpan.node().textContent = catched? "Perfect! :)" : "Oh no! :(";
  });
</script>
```

My code is running on https://jsfiddle.net/avi5102005/uh627zt5/62/.

Can somebody guide me the way I should have approached? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add Id to your circles

```
const catchCircle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('cx', width / 2)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr("id", "catch") //add ID
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)
  .attr('fill', 'none');

const preyCircle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', radius)
  .attr('cx', width / 2)
  .attr('cy', height - radius)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .attr("id", "prey") //add ID 
  .transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .delay(1000)
    .attr('cy', radius)
    .remove();
```

next, on your button press do:

```
d3.select('#catchMe')
    .on('click', () => {
    catched = false;
     let py = d3.select("#prey").attr("cy"); // get prey's y
     let px = d3.select("#prey").attr("cx"); // get prey's x
     let pr = +d3.select("#prey").attr("r"); // get prey's radius

     let cy = d3.select("#catch").attr("cy");
     let cx = d3.select("#catch").attr("cx");
     let cr = +d3.select("#catch").attr("r");

     //Pythagoras distance formula
     let distance = Math.pow(px-cx, 2) + Math.pow(py-cy, 2);
     catched = Math.sqrt(distance) < cr + pr; //check if overlap

    const msgSpan = d3.select('#msg');
    msgSpan.node().textContent = catched? "Perfect! :)" : "Oh no! :(";
  });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbskm2n0/)